# How to get Pages Per Session Total in google analytics data?

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I am using google analytics API got fetching data. I successfully fetched data for Sessions and Bounce Rate. Now want to show **Pages Per Session Total** but i am not find this how to get this .Anyone help to find out this.For session and Bounce Rate i used this query.

```
    $query = $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $ga_profile_id, $start_date, $end_date, 'ga:sessions', array('max-results' => 10000));

    $query = $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $ga_profile_id, $start_date, $end_date, 'ga:visitBounceRate', array('max-results' => 1000, 'dimensions' => 'ga:channelGrouping',));

  if ($query['totalResults'] != 0 && isset($query['rows'])) {
    $bounce_rate_total = round($query['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visitBounceRate'],2);
    print 'Bounce Rate Total: '.$bounce_rate_total.'<br/>';
    $bounce_rate_organic = round($query['rows'][2][1],2);
    print 'Bounce Rate organic: '.$bounce_rate_organic.'<br/>';
    $bounce_rate_ppc = round($query['rows'][3][1],2);
    print 'Bounce Rate PPC: '.$bounce_rate_ppc.'<br/>';
    $bounce_rate_social = round($query['rows'][5][1],2);
    print 'Bounce Rate Social: '.$bounce_rate_social.'<br/>';
  }
```

[image]
Thanks

Comment: pages per session or pageviewsPerSession ?

Comment: Pages per session